# Regex for selecting words ending in 'ing' unless

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I want to select words ending in with a regular expression, but I want exclude words that end in `thing`.  For example:

```
everything
running 
catching 
nothing
```

Of these words, running and catching should be selected, everything and nothing should be excluded.

I've tried the following:

```
.+ing$
```

But that selects everything.  I'm thinking look aheads/look arounds could be the solution, but I haven't been able to get one that works.

Solutions that work in Python or R would be helpful.

Comment: Use `\b\w*ing\b(?<!thing)` or `\b\w*(?<!th)ing\b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python you can use negative lookbehind assertion as this:

```
^.*(?<!th)ing$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9zqkCH/1)

`(?<!th)` is negative lookbehind expression that will fail the match if `th` comes before `ing` at the end of string.

Note that if you are matching words that are not on separate lines then instead of anchors use word boundaries as:

```
\w+(?<!th)ing\b
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like `\b\w+(?<!th)ing\b` maybe.

Answer (score 2):

You might also use a negative lookahead `(?!` to assert that what is on the right is not 0+ times a word character followed by `thing` and a word boundary:

`\b(?!\w*thing\b)\w*ing\b`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dhDcNj/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/R3sRhW)

Comment: Think you need to add `ing` to the end of your regex so that it does not match words that do not end in "ing".